# Reduce loadtime on Joomla 1.7 by avoiding mootools

Tags: joomla, mootools, joomla1.7

How do we avoid loading mootools on the frontpage, while still allow it to load on pages where mootools is required?

In a recent project we are using Joomla 1.7 and at this stage we are using one of the default templates. It seems that mootools (core & more) is always loaded, bumping the frontpage up to 500+ Kbytes where the mootools are the major part in that size. We want to avoid mootools, at least on the frontpage, while we are aware that some modules might need the mootools.

I have the impression that mootools shouls only be loaded when the modules require it. Is that true and where do I find an overview of which standard modules that are using mootools? Because then we can avoid those on the frontpage.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that even the template you are using requires Mootools.

The right way to load mootools is using this:

```
JHTML::_( 'behavior.mootools' );
```

So you should search for that in the modules, components, plugins and template you are using. Any way, if you use the compressed version of mootools and use gzip compression for the output, you should see the amount of kb really go down.

I hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have the impression that it is not the way it works in Joomla 1.7.

First the load of mootools is "requested" the way you write, and then Joomla loads mootools.
Secondly I wanted an overview of which templates, modules and plugin that standard requests mootools.
Thirdly the size goes down a little when using the compressed version, but the newest mootools (core & more) are still about 300 Kbytes.

Comment: 88 Kbytes for mootools-core and 238 Kbytes for mootools-more.

Comment: Maybe another solution is using some kind of css / js compressor, like rokgzipper (http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-joomla/rokgzipper). Maybe the size won't reduce too much, but you'll save many http requests (that's what takes most time). Besides, if you still want to "force" joomla to don't use mootools, you can do it using a plugin and using the "onBeforeRender" event to manually remove document scripts you want (mootools.js and mootools-more.js or whatever). But I think this might break many of you javascript, since Joomla ships Mootools on its core.

Comment: I use the Google compressed version. Core is not the issue, more IS. GZIP is also enabled, so we are talking about the FILES - mootools is bloated and TOTALLY unnecessary for many purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla loads mootools by default; always when it needs it anyway.  I believe there are plugins available to turn off mootools where/when/how you want.  See this thread: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2516614 - they discuss disabling it and give various ways to go about it; as well as discussing the downfalls of doing so.
Here is a plugin that does what you want as well: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/scripts/15748

Comment: Thanks. The plug-in can disable mootools-core and NOT mootools-more.

It is apparently a mistake in the design of Joomla 1.7.

Comment: I have tried with a VERY simple template, and mootools (core & more) is still loaded. Seems that Joomla 1.7 is still in early testing stage, since I can believe a good CMS is so bad and undocumented.
I am still open for things and issues I have missed, as I am still positive.

Comment: By further tweaking, changes in various files and having a custom template, I am able to avoid mootools on the Home page and load it on the few pages that need it. Page size went from about 450 Kbytes to 5 Kbytes.

Comment: Could you document what you did specifically?  I'm curious just because I remember at one time doing something somewhat similar on 1.5 - but haven't tried it on 1.7.

Comment: This is what I did with Joomla - which is obviously still in early testing phases, and Kunena. I had to always load core, which bumped the size up to 35 Kbytes.
Made an light version of a beez template.
Disabled various unneeded things on the FrontPage.
Added GoogleAjaxLib and Disable Mootools Plug-ins, and configured them.
Set the order to: Disable Mootools, GoogleAjaxLib and Kunena.
There are still things left to optimize, but this reduces size of the Frontpage by 90%.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code above the `<jdoc:include type="head" />`

```
$header = $this->getHeadData();
$header['scripts'] = array('/my-js.js'=> array ('mime' =>'text/javascript','defer'=>'','async'=>''));
$this->setHeadData($header);
```

Comment: The code provided renders nicely as text in the browser. It does not change the loading of mootools core & more.

Comment: You should put a <?php `CODE_HERE` ?> around it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the mootools upgrade plugin.

Comment: Disabling MooTools plugin will load MooTools 1.1 not removing MooTools completely.